# get a specific sequence from a fasta file with Regex

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, fasta

I would like to retrieve the n<sup>th</sup> sequence (or preferably n<sup>th</sup> to m<sup>th</sup> sequence) from a input fasta file, ideally with a unix "one-liner".

I know I could read the sequence with perl (or any other scripting language), count, and then print the sequence, but I'm looking for something faster and more compact.

For those unaware, a sample fasta file looks like the following:

```
>SEQUENCE_1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL
>SEQUENCE_2
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to reflect precisely what you are looking for? Something like this is my desired output and this is what I have tried.

Comment: @Endoro Sorry if that was unclear. If I have 10 sequences in the fasta file and want to retrieve the 5th one, then n would be 5. I would need the header (which starts with >) and the lines below it until the next >, which marks the next sequence.
Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='>' -v start=$n -v end=$m 'NR>=(start+1)&&NR<=(end+1){print ">"$0}' fasta_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways using `awk`.

If your sequences are wrapped 1 per line, this would work:

```
awk -v n=5 -v m=8 'NR == n * 2 - 1, NR == m * 2' file.fa
```

If your sequence lines aren't wrapped, then this may be more appropriate:

```
awk -v n=5 -v m=8 '/^>/ { c++ } c == n { f=1 } c == m + 1 { f=0 } f' file.fa
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/SEQUENCE_'$n'/,/SEQUENCE_'$(($m + 1))'/p' input | sed '$d'
```

Answer (score 2):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) one liner (no pipe `|` needed):

```
sed '/>SEQUENCE_'$n'/, />SEQUENCE_'$(($m + 1))'/!d;{/>SEQUENCE_'$(($m + 1))'/d}' file
```